# Copying a set of strings to local variables based on a keyword

Tags: java, image, href

I need to extract http links from a set of text information. Particular phrases which has image extenstions(.jpg, .png)

For example, I want alone "http://www.mywedding.com/blog/wp-content/gallery/p_867/bridal-party-white-flowers-40306.jpg"

from the below set of thing

```
 <p><a href="http://www.mywedding.com/blog/wp-content/gallery/p_867/bridal-party-white-flowers-40306.jpg" target="_blank"><a href="http://www.mywedding.com/blog/wp-content/gallery/p_867/bridal-party-white-flowers-40306.jpg">http://www.mywedding.com/blog/wp-content/gallery/p_867/bridal-party-white-flowers-40306.jpg</a></a> (from <a href="http://cameroningalls.com/emily-meeko-tiburon/" target="_blank">this wedding by Cameron Ingalls</a>)</p>
```

If those are img tags, i can get it from simple appraoch

```
String s="<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUSRH.jpg"/> 

s=s.replace("<img src=", "");
s=s.replace("/>", "");
```

But I am confused to get through first scenario, Any suggestions for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have the raw information in a single string? This looks like a classic job for regular expressions. I would check this site,

9: HTML tag Regular Expression Pattern
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/

And there's a pretty good explanation of how to use it here:
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-extract-html-links-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex to match it.

(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*

use the links darkpbj provided if you need to know how to use it and to learn about regex. pretty powerful stuff.

good luck.